# Visual 2013.Error C2065: cout: необъявленный идентификатор

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include"stdafx.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
  char Letters[6] = "Hello";
  cout << Letters;
}
```

Comment: В коде проблем нет, что-то не так с проектом, значит. Попробуйте пересоздать проект. И создавайте пустой проект в студии, в который потом добавляйте cpp файл.

Comment: Насколько я помню, stdafx.h должен всегда включаться первым.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    char Letters[6] = "Hello";
    cout << Letters;
    return 0;
}
```

Этот вариант рабочий. Строка *#include "stdafx.h"* должна быть в начале.

Кстати, сам код файла stdfx.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
```

Проверьте, он вам действительно нужен?

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream>
#include"stdafx.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
  char Letters[6] = "Hello";
  cout << Letters;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Думаете добавление `return` решит проблему ошибку касательно `cout`?

Comment: Думаете компилятор не выдаст ошибку без него? Проблем в коде нет говорите? ...

Comment: Я уверен, что не выдаст. Это разрешено стандартом(3.6.1/5): `A return statement in main has the effect of leaving the main function (destroying any objects with automaticstorage duration) and calling std::exit with the return value as the argument. If control reaches the end
of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing return 0;`